# React hooks clone a component on the base of quantity prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to clone component on the base of quantity prop, like here i have one Div

[image]

And i want to replicate this Div Element on this base of Qunatity Prop

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
const quantityOfSomething new Array(quantity).fill('anything')

return (
<div>
   {quantityOfSomething.map(
      (item, index) => <div key={`${item}-${index}`}>i am a new div</div>
    )}
</div>
)
```